# VF controller function referenced by apex:actionSupport not firing

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

I'm trying to call this function but the debug statement is not working.

```html
<apex:selectList value="{!year}" title="Yıl" id="yearFilter" multiSelect="false" size="1" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!years}"/>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setSelectedMethod}" reRender="refreshSection" status="status" />
        </apex:selectList>
```

Apex

```java
public void setSelectedMethod(){
        System.debug('setselectedmethod##');
        dataRefresh(userId);
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i presume your debug logging level is set to Apex DEBUG and not INFO, WARN, or ERROR?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have given is working for me (I'm getting a debug).

Perhaps the mistake is elsewhere?

Working code:

```
<apex:page controller="sotestcontroller">
    <apex:form>


    <apex:selectList value="{!year}" title="Yıl" id="yearFilter" multiSelect="false" size="1" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!years}"/>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setSelectedMethod}" reRender="refreshSection" status="status" />
        </apex:selectList>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

```
public class sotestcontroller {
    public String year {get; set;}
    public list<Selectoption> years {get; set;}

    public sotestcontroller(){

        this.years = new list<selectOption>();
        years.add(new SelectOption('1','1'));
        years.add(new selectOption('2', '2'));

    }

    public void setSelectedMethod(){
        System.debug('setselectedmethod##');
        //dataRefresh(userId);
    }
```